# Not able to find the string modified in subsequent filters using tap operator

Tags: rxjs

I have implemented a logic in my angular component that will display the version number  against the Agreement.pdf like Agreement_v1.pdf as well as set the editable flag to true to any document that is not Identification and also Agreement document that is not v1. As you can see the version number logic is applied in the first tap operator. Unfortunately I think my second tap operator does find such occurrence. Could somebody tell me why ?

```
var first: number = 1;

if (this.readOnly) {
  this.columnsToDisplay = ['category', 'filename', 'uploadedOnDate'];
} else {
  this.columnsToDisplay = ['category', 'filename', 'uploadedOnDate', 'action', 'delete'];
}

const investigationDocuments = this.caseChange$
  .pipe(
    map(investigationsCase => {
      this.configureSendNewAgreement(investigationsCase.state.documents);
      return investigationsCase.state.documents
        ? investigationsCase.state.documents.filter(doc => doc.isActive === true)
        : [];
    }),
    tap(a => a.filter(d => d.type === TypeOfDocument.Agreement).sort((x, y) => +new Date(x.uploadedOnDate) - +new Date(y.uploadedOnDate)).forEach(b => b.name = 'Agreement_v' + (first++) +'.pdf')),
    tap(a => a.filter(d => d.type !== TypeOfDocument.Identification && d.uploadedBy != null && d.name !== 'Agreement_v1.pdf').forEach(b => b.isEditable = true)),
  );
```

Comment: It is very hard to identify what is wrong here without more information. Would it be possible to put fake data into the map instead to see what the shape of the data is coming in? Even better would be if you could setup a StackBlitz example. They have an RxJs template which should be sufficient for your question as the code you provided has nothing to do with Angular.

Answer (score 0):

The `tap` operator doesn't modify the incoming value. So anything you'd do to `a` within the `tap` is ignored.

From the docs:

> Used when you want to affect outside state with a notification without altering the notification

In other words, only use `tap` if you want to do some debugging or a side effect that does not change the notification (incoming variable).

Try changing both `tap` operators to `map` and see if that helps.

The map allows changing the incoming variable and it emits that changed variable to the next operator in the pipeline.

I did a stackblitz to show the difference:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tap-vs-map-deborahk

**Component**

```js
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  name = 'Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  result$ = of(SampleData).pipe(
    tap(a => a.filter(d => !d.startsWith('t'))),
    tap(a => a.filter(d => !d.startsWith('f')))
  )

  result2$ = of(SampleData).pipe(
    map(a => a.filter(d => !d.startsWith('t'))),
    map(a => a.filter(d => !d.startsWith('f')))
  )

  constructor() {
    this.result$.subscribe(result => console.log('Result: ', JSON.stringify(result)))
    this.result2$.subscribe(result => console.log('Result2: ', JSON.stringify(result)))
  }
}

export const SampleData = [
  "one",
  "two",
  "three",
  "four",
  "five"
]
```

**Result**

```
Result: ["one","two","three","four","five"]
Result2: ["one"]
```

Notice that the first statement uses `tap` and the result is unchanged from the original sample data array.

The second statement uses `map` and the filtered results are propagated through the pipeline and appear in the result.